# Newline/Linefeed character validation XSD

Tags: regex, xsd

I would like to validate and restrict newline/linefeed character.

Valid XML:

```
<root>
  <node>data data</node>
</root>
```

Invalid XML:

```
    <root>
      <node>data
data</node>
    </root>
```

I am not sure how to use RegEx for this. Newline/Linefeed character may appear at any position in data and that XML should be called as Invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helped myself. Here is an answer. (Updated as per Petru's comment .. so credit goes to Petru rather :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="node" type="SUBTYPE" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="SUBTYPE">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value=".*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Actually, while it is correct, it is not the simplest; . (the dot) by definition is anything except \n\r; which means .* should suffice. Try it (I did!) and maybe update the answer with the simpler version.